# Android device to device comminication using wifi

Tags: android, wifi, communication

I have 2 android devices and I need to communicate between the two using wifi to send and receive data. What is a reliable method to send/receive data over a private wifi signal, preferably without rooting (I already know how to do it if rooted, but I really don't want to root my phone (I'm rooting my tablet)).

I don't mind writing a lot of code myself, just looking for a method or class to send data and receive it over wifi, with examples.

Comment: Do you mean having the devices directly connected to each other like with `WiFi Direct` or just a standard network socket connection?

Comment: Either works, but im trying to get direct. Im writing this to allow device to device communication without bluetooth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refer to the official Android developer site to learn more about the [WIFI Direct API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). This is the official documentation and you can attempt the demo to get started.

Comment: Thanks, but i am unable to find the demo. Could you provide a link?

Comment: @azulflame Go to your sdk location>samples>android-14>WifiDirectDemo

Comment: I don't have an SDK... I program FROM a droid FOR droids. I use AIDE, and it works great. Coby KYROS tablet. Hence why i asked for some code

Comment: @azulflame try to download the sdk on your pc and see the sources, there are so many classes that's why I can't paste code for you here.